# Coalesce columns and replace NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4c9ec71282a14812e19a7d6ec1e9b3fe)**

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    event_type VARCHAR (255),
    date_offered DATE,
    date_ordered DATE, 
    date_delivered DATE,
    quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(id, campaign, event_type, 
date_offered, date_ordered, date_delivered, quantity
)
VALUES 
("1", "C001", "offered", "2019-04-10", NULL, NULL, "500"),
("2", "C001", "ordered", NULL, "2019-04-16", NULL, "450"),
("3", "C001", "stored", NULL, NULL, "2019-04-18", NULL),

("4", "C002", "offered", "2019-08-14", NULL, NULL, "700"),
("5", "C002", "ordered", NULL, "2019-09-04", NULL, "730"),
("6", "C002", "stored", NULL, NULL, "2019-09-15", "800");
```

I want to run a query that `coalesce` the values so:

a) all `date values` are in one column called `event_date` and 
b) in case there is no `quantity` for the `event_type` `stored` (as you can see for `C001`) the `quantity` of the `event_type` `order` should be used.

The result should look like this:

```
campaign     event_type       event_date         quantity
C001         offered          2019-04-10          500
C001         ordered          2019-04-16          450
C001         stored           2019-04-18          450
C002         offered          2019-08-14          700
C002         ordered          2019-09-04          730
C002         stored           2019-09-15          800
```

I tried to go with this:

```
SELECT id,
       campaign,
       event_type,
       coalesce(date_offered, date_ordered, date_delivered) as event_date,
       quantity
  FROM logistics;
```

With this query I get close to my expected results but for `C001` there is a `NULL` for `C001` in the `event_type` `stored`.

How do I have to modify my query to get the `quantity` of the `event_type` `ordered` for the `event_type` `stored` for `C001`?

Comment: I think you should go back to your previous schema. I preferred it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT id, campaign, event_type,
       coalesce(date_offered, date_ordered, date_delivered) as event_date,
       coalesce(quantity,
                max(case when event_type = 'ordered' then quantity end) over (partition by campaign)
               ) as new_quantity
FROM logistics;
```

In older versions, you can use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT l.id, l.campaign, l.event_type,
       coalesce(l.date_offered, l.date_ordered, l.date_delivered) as event_date,
       coalesce(l.quantity, lo.quantity
               ) as new_quantity
FROM logistics l LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT lo.campaign, MAX(lo.quantity) as quantity
      FROM logistics lo
      WHERE lo.event_type = 'ordered'
      GROUP BY lo.campaign
     ) lo
     USING (campaign);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume this only works with mySQL 8.0 but I only have mySQL 5.7. Is there also a solution for older versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *correlated* sub-query :

```
SELECT l.id, l.campaign, l.event_type,
       coalesce(l.date_offered, l.date_ordered, l.date_delivered) as event_date,
       coalesce(l.quantity,
                      (SELECT MAX(l1.quantity)
                       FROM logistics l1
                       WHERE l1.event_type = 'ordered' AND l.campaign = l1.campaign
                      )
               ) as new_quantity
FROM logistics l;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logic similar to self join for the table `logistics` where the part after `JOIN` clause would be a nested query filtered out through `event_type = 'ordered'` and grouped by `campaign` column :

```
SELECT id, l1.campaign, event_type,
       COALESCE(date_offered, date_ordered, date_delivered) AS event_date,
       COALESCE(l1.quantity,l2.quantity) AS quantity 
  FROM logistics l1
  JOIN ( SELECT campaign, MAX(quantity) AS quantity 
           FROM logistics 
          WHERE event_type = 'ordered' 
          GROUP BY campaign  )  l2
    ON l2.campaign = l1.campaign
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=72ab4906125e1e54c212d74487caea10)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this strikes me as a better schema:

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+----------+
| id | campaign | event_type | event_date | quantity |
+----+----------+------------+------------+----------+
|  1 |    1     | offered    | 2019-04-10 | 500      |
|  2 |    2     | offered    | 2019-08-14 | 700      |
|  3 |    1     | ordered    | 2019-04-16 | 450      |
|  4 |    2     | ordered    | 2019-09-04 | 730      |
|  5 |    1     | stored     | 2019-04-18 | NULL     |
|  6 |    2     | stored     | 2019-09-15 | 800      |
+----+----------+------------+------------+----------+
```